# 'type' object is not iterable when iterating list in class

Tags: python

When using this code:

```
import random

class result:
    list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    def choicename(self):
        for i in list:
            if i == list[0]:
                result = random.randint(90, 100)
            else:
                result = random.randint(0, 10)

        print 'The %s result is %d' % (i, result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = result()
    t.choicename()
```

I get an error:

```
  File "D:\Program\test\test\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    t.choicename()
  File "D:\Program\test\test\__init__.py", line 13, in choicename
    for i in list:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Why is that? `list` looks iterable to me.

Comment: `list` in `choicename` refers to the `list` type. If you want `result.list`, that’s what you’ll need to use.

Comment: Perhaps the PERFECT example why you should NEVER use `list` as a name for a variable!!!

Comment: thank,i already fix it ,now it run ok!

Answer (score 2):

`list` in `choicename` refers to the `list` type. If you want `result.list`, that’s what you’ll need to use.